# how do i complete an if statement to see if a valid direction was entered

Tags: java, netbeans

This is a program I'm writing for school, its a 2D array adventure game. I need help with the blank if statement. It needed to know if a valid direction was entered. I'm just not sure where to go from here. I also want to make it so there is an amount of keys to access the locked rooms. I'm not very talented at coding so this may seem messy, but I'ts the best I have. How can i do this?

```
package hauntedhouse;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HauntedHouse {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);

        String room[][] = new String[2][2];         // allocate 2 dimensional array of strings

        //This section of code fills the 2D array with room names
        room[0][0] = "Entry Hall";
        //code to fill the rest of the rooms here
        room[1][0] = "Dining Room";
        room[2][0] = "Master Bedroom";
        room[0][1] = "Storage [locked]";
        room[1][1] = "Grand Hall";
        room[2][1] = "Bedroom";
        room[0][2] = "Garage [locked]";
        room[1][2] = "Back Door";
        room[2][2] = "";



        int x = 0;  // the coordinates of the room to start
        int y = 0;

        String di = ""; // variable used to hold the direction they entered
            System.out.println("Theres a secret in this house,");
            System.out.println("go into the locked rooms to find"); 
            System.out.println("out what it is, have these two keys!");
        do {

            System.out.println("You are now in the " + room[x][y]);

            //this next loop will repeat until a valid direction is entered
            while (true) //this loop continues until the "break" statement is executed
            {
                System.out.println("Enter your direction");
                if () //figure this out!!
                {
                    break;          //exits while loop
                }
            } // end while (true)

            if (di.equals("W"))
            {
               y = y+1; 
            } else if (di.equals("A")) {
               x = x-1;                 
            } else if (di.equals("S")) {
               y = y-1;                 
            } else if (di.equals("D"))  {
               x = x+1;                              
            } else {
              //an illegal direction has been entered           
         }
   }
  while (x>=2); }// end when you make it to the locked room SOMEHOW

   } // TODO code application logic here
```

Comment: 1st replace the if else if ladder with a switch where you check for the direction. 2nd try to make a flow chart (not a formal one but with arrows and boxes) explaining the flow of your program (it might take a while) after that is done try to figure out the code again I bet it will be a lot easier.

Comment: `String di = "";`why not be descriptive as in `String directionTheyEntered = "";`

Comment: Think "what are valid directions" (it is unclear to me really here) then "how can I store those valid directions?" then 'How can I check if it IS a valid direction (look in my stored values) - note for "simple" programs for beginners it is probably OK to hard code those "directions" in, is "a" or "b" or "c" or "d" then do x else do y

Answer (score 0):

To validate a 2D array you can simply use [`.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) function

```
 String room [][] = new String [2][2];
 room[0][0] = "Entry Hall";
 if(room[0][0].equals("Entry Hall")){
  System.out.println("Inside Entry Hall");
 }
```